# SQL query to get all the data in specific range

Tags: sql

I have a table(offer) with three columns, id, product_id and price.

```
offer
----- 
id (integer)   
product_id (integer)
price (decimal)
```

I wanted to fire a SQL query which will return the number of offers between a price range.
range should be like 0-1, 1-2, 2-3 etc

```
price_lower   price_upper    number_of_offers
-------------------------------------------------------------
0                     1            4
1                     2            1
2                     3            0
3                     4            6
4                     5            2
... etc
```

I did this to get the number of offers between 0 and 1

```
SELECT * FROM offer WHERE price BETWEEN 0 and 1;
```

What should be the query to get desired result.

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have double counts if you don't separate your grouping better.  IE: price_upper = 1 and on the 2nd row - price_lower = 1; this means you'll count where price is 1 in both totals.

Comment: Some of the solutions being proposed will only work for certain SQL products - it would help if you could let us know which database software you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Checking all the answers. I have managed to write the query of course with your help.
As few of you suggested to create a new table to store offer range which i don't want to do.

So, here is the SQL query what i wanted:

```
SELECT price as price_lower, (price + 1) as price_upper, (SELECT count(*) from offer WHERE price BETWEEN o.price and (o.price + 0.99)) from offer o GROUP BY price;
```

Thanks to all for your great efforts. You guys rock.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @Offer TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        Product_ID INT,
        Price FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 0
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, .25
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, .5
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, .75
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 1.
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 1.25
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 1.5
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 1.75
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 1, 2.

INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 1.25
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 1.5
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 1.75
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 2.
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 2.25
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 2.5
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 2.75
INSERT INTO @Offer SELECT 2, 3.

SELECT  Product_ID,
        FLOOR(Price) StartPrice,
        FLOOR(Price) + 1 EndPrice,
        COUNT(1) NumberItems
FROM    @Offer
GROUP BY Product_ID,
        FLOOR(Price)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUM(number_of_offers) FROM offer WHERE price_lower >= [lowest price] AND price_upper <= [highest price].

The bits in square brackets you will have to fill in, for example you might substitue parameters there.

Comment: Damn, i would mark down my own post if i could - i didn't read the qwuestion properly. Meh.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you listed:

```
SELECT MIN(t.price) 'price_lower',
       MAX(t.price) 'price_upper',
       COUNT(*) 'number_of_offers'
  FROM OFFER t
 WHERE t.price BETWEEN 0 AND 1
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(t.price) 'price_lower',
       MAX(t.price) 'price_upper',
       COUNT(*) 'number_of_offers'
  FROM OFFER t
 WHERE t.price BETWEEN 1 AND 2
UNION ALL
...
```

...adding distinct SQL statements for each grouping you want, changing the WHERE clause to suit.

Comment: There's no need to have a bunch of unioned queries like this, it can be done in a single query using floor/ceiling/group-by.

Comment: @Chris: There is if FLOOR/CEILING isn't supported by the DB, which the OP has yet to provide.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
select floor(price) as price_lower,
       ceiling(price) as price_upper,
       count(*) as offercount
   from tbl_offer
   group by floor(price), ceiling(price)
```

For the following test data:

```
insert into tbl_offer ([product_id],[price]) values (1, 1.9)
insert into tbl_offer ([product_id],[price]) values (2, 2.2)
insert into tbl_offer ([product_id],[price]) values (3, 2.3)
insert into tbl_offer ([product_id],[price]) values (4, 4.5)
insert into tbl_offer ([product_id],[price]) values (5, 2.7)
```

I got the following results:

```
price_lower price_upper offercount  
----------- ----------- ----------- 
1           2           1
2           3           3
4           5           1
```

The only thing missing from the example table you gave is that I don't have a line with price_lower 3, price_upper 4, offercount 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct. One caveat is that if anything costs an integral amount, it will show up depending on your flavor of sql because "between" is sometimes inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table offer_range (price_lower integer, price_upper integer);

insert into offer_range (price_lower, price_upper) 
values (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), -- ...etc
;

select r.price_lower,
r.price_upper,
(
select count(*)
from offer o 
where o.price between r.price_lower and r.price_upper
) as number_of_offers
from offer_range r
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one allows you to set a separate **PriceRange** table with ranges for each product.

```
DECLARE @Offer TABLE(
     ID INT IDENTITY (1,1)
     ,Product_ID INT
     ,Price decimal(8,2)
)

DECLARE @PriceRange TABLE(
     ID INT IDENTITY (1,1)
     ,Product_ID INT
     ,price_lower decimal(8,2)
     ,price_upper decimal(8,2)
)

SELECT x.Product_ID,  x.price_lower, x.price_upper, COUNT(*) as "number_of_offers"
   FROM 
    (
    SELECT o.Product_ID, o.Price, p.price_lower, p.price_upper,
      CASE 
        WHEN o.Price >= p.price_lower and o.Price < p.price_upper THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS InRange           
    FROM @Offer AS o
      JOIN  @PriceRange as p ON o.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
    ) AS x
WHERE x.InRange = 1
GROUP BY x.Product_ID, x.price_lower, x.price_upper
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need specify a max number of ranges, please try this approach:
You can indicate a max number of price ranges and it's automatically created the group price ranges and totals.

```
declare @Max_Steps int
set @Max_Steps= 6

select Price_Group * data.Price_Step as price_lower, (Price_Group+1)*data.Price_Step as price_upper, count(id) as number_of_offers
from
(
    select id, price, ceiling(price/Price_Step) as Price_Group, Price_Step
    from
    (
        select cast((max(price) - min(price))/@Max_Steps as decimal(15,2))  as Price_Step
        FROM offer
    ) PriceRangeCalculator
cross join  
    (
        SELECT id, price
        FROM offer
    ) SourceData
) data
group by data.Price_Group, data.Price_Step
order by data.Price_Group
```